# Code for ST7789 NO CS pin - Using XIAO ESP32C3

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, tft

I am trying to get anything out of this screen except for blackness. The CS pin is present based on the coupling or resistors and capacitors on the back of the display.

I have tried using the Arduino ST7789 fast library, but I am wondering if anyone has gotten that to work in recent times. I first get an error saying no such library for avr/pgmspace. I found a fix to that issue by adding:

```
 #if (defined(__AVR__))
 #include <avr\pgmspace.h>
 #else
 #include <pgmspace.h>
 #endif
```

but then I move right to another error saying:

```
In member function 'void Arduino_ST7789::commonST7789Init(const uint8_t*)':
Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:114:70: error: cannot convert 'volatile uint32_t*' {aka 'volatile long unsigned int*'} to 'volatile uint8_t*' {aka 'volatile unsigned char*'} in assignment
 #define portOutputRegister(port)    ((volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_OUT_REG)
```

I have found nobody else with this issue.

Here is my pinout:

| Esp32c3 | St7789 |
| --- | --- |
| GPIO 2 | DC |
| GPIO 3 | RES |
| GPIO 6 | SDA |
| GPIO 7 | SCL |
| 3v3 | Vcc/Lite |

[Here is the screen in question](https://www.cesdeals.com/products/1-3-inch-ips-display-module-7-pin-st7789-rgb-tft-lcd-board-electronic-components-1011681?variant=a6b9e525-1b3a-43f5-9673-059064524ae9&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA_OetBhAtEiwAPTeQZ0zXtYi0e8tRGx-Ckaw2FdxrvzM_0-HwqKagK3RS5XQGbYtqnO_1oBoCGV4QAvD_BwE) and
[here is the microcontroller in question](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO_ESP32C3_Getting_Started/)

I have also used the normal ST7789 library and substituted -1 for the CS pin, but still black on my display. If anyone can provide any raw code to get this to work or just let me know where to begin on trying new code please let me know.

Comment: The library is optimised for AVR chip using some AVR register and assembly code, it is therefore not compatible with ESP32 in the default mode. Add `#define COMPATIBILITY_MODE` to the first line of your code (before any `#include <file>` macro to see if it is working. If not, use other library such Adafruit ST7789 library.